# Randomly choosing one outlet and setting others

Tags: ios, swift, random, uibutton, variable-assignment

I have a function that chooses a  random`UIButton` and sets its character to a certain emoji.  I want to now set the remaining`UIButtons` to be random emojis.

How would I determine which`UIButtons` were not set from the random generator assigning one a value?

Also I want to make sure that the value being assigned is not the same as the value that was inserted at the random generator.

```
@IBOutlet weak var topLeftAnswer: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var topRightAnswer: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomLeftAnswer: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomRightAnswer: UIButton!

 func correctAnswerGen() {
    var correct: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    switch correct{
    case 0: topLeftAnswer.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    case 1: topRightAnswer.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    case 2: bottomLeftAnswer.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    case 3: bottomRightAnswer.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    default: break
    }
    //assign other 3 buttons to another emoji value.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing simplified:

```
func randomEmoji() -> String{
    let emojies = [UInt32](0x1F601...0x1F64F)
    + [UInt32](0x2702...0x27B0)
    + [UInt32](0x1F680...0x1F6C0)
    + [UInt32](0x1F170...0x1F251)

    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(emojies.count - 1)))

    return String(UnicodeScalar(emojies[rand]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a random emoji, you can loop through `0x1F601...0x1F64F`, and select a random emoji like:

```
var rand: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(78)

for i in 0x1F601...0x1F64F {
    if rand == i {
          var c = String(UnicodeScalar(i))
          print(c)
          break
    }
}
```

But as there are many more emojis, you'll have to use something like this, to loop though all of them:

```
let allEmojis = [
    0x1F601...0x1F64F,
    0x2702...0x27B0,
    0x1F680...0x1F6C0,
    0x1F170...0x1F251
]

var rand: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(544)
var counter = 0
for range in allEmojis {
    for i in range {
        if rand == counter
        {
            var c = String(UnicodeScalar(i))
            print(c)
        }
        counter++
    }
}
```